# honeysql merge-where building a large query

Tags: clojure, honeysql

I'm trying to use honeysql to programmatically build a query, adding on where clauses as I go.

Coming from python and using sqlalchemy, I can do something like:

```
In [3]: query = model.Account.query
In [4]: query = query.filter_by(id=1)
In [5]: query = query.filter_by(email='abc@foo.com')
In [6]: query = query.filter_by(username='someuser')
In [7]: query = query.filter_by(is_active=1)
In [8]: printquery(query)

SELECT *
FROM account
WHERE account.id = 1 AND account.email = 'abc@foo.com' 
      AND account.username = 'someuser' AND account.is_active = 1
```

However, using honeysql, my where clause isn't as clean.

```
user=> (require '[honeysql.core :as sql])
user=> (require '[honeysql.helpers :refer :all])
user=> (->
  #_=>   (select :*)
  #_=>   (from :test)
  #_=>   (merge-where [:= :a 1])
  #_=>   (merge-where [:= :b 2])
  #_=>   (merge-where [:= :c 3])
  #_=>   (merge-where [:= :d 4])
  #_=>   sql/format)

["SELECT * FROM test WHERE (((a = 1 AND b = 2) AND c = 3) AND d = 4)"]
```

I am aware that they're logically the same thing, but as I start to get more and more complex, I'm starting to get nervous that I'm gonna get some subtle query acting weird with extra parens that causes me problems.

Am I being crazy? Should I stop worrying and learn to love the extra parens (It is clojure after all)? Or is there a better pattern for query building I'm not aware of? Should I build my where clauses as a big vector, and add them all to the query map at the very end?

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Look at it from a logical perspective

```
a AND b AND c = ( a AND b ) AND c = a AND ( b AND c ).
```

where a, b and c are propositions like

```
A = 1
```

The AND operator is associative, meaning that it doesn't matter where the parenthesis are placed, or how many, as long as the sequence of the propositions remains the same.

Worked out examples [here.](http://kias.dyndns.org/comath/22.html)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. Yeah, I mentioned I realized they were logically the same result, and I haven't yet come up with some example of "Oh man, after the 12th weird clause I added, the parens become a problem!" - I was just hoping there was a cleaner result. In my code, I've adapted to building up a list of clauses, and then using `merge-where` once at the end in a big `[:and]` clause. Thanks again!